# The length is decreased on overwriting an mp3 file using FFmpeg command

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to compress an audio file and I use `-y` command to overwrite the existing file. But problem is that that command decreases the duration of the audio file.

I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i D:\audio\Blues.mp3 -ab 64 D:\audio\Blues.mp3
```

Is there any way to resolve this within `ffmpeg`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read from a file and write to it at the same time with FFmpeg.

Write to a different file, then delete the original afterwards.

Comment: Gonna have to patch this to check if output == input.

Comment: @Gyan I think this is a great idea if you're throwing a warning but not explicitly blocking it.  There may be implementations, particularly with URLs and such where it may be valid (even if oddball and confusing) to read and write from the same place.  But, this question comes up on Stack Overflow all the time so I think a warning is definitely appropriate!

Comment: The patch will ignore pipes and will compare full URLs. Can you give me an example of a command where reading and writing to the same full URL is valid and fruitful?

Comment: @Gyan Suppose this person was reading from and POST-ing to an S3 bucket.  (Or most any other similar service.)  The full new resource has to be received by the server before the original is replaced.  So, I could read from `http://example.com/test.mkv` and write to `http://example.com/test.mkv` and it's up to the server to decide how to handle that overwrite behavior.  In fact, the server may choose to do something entirely different!  While it's RESTful treat the resource as the same, it's common where different methods do different things.  That's not required for the side effect though.

Comment: In that case, it's better to add an option, disabled by default, to allow same URL overwrites. The problem with warnings is it's too late if the destination doesn't allow handling like that.

Comment: @Gyan The problem with outright blocking someone from doing something is that you don't know whether they can do it or not, or what their intentions are.  FFmpeg is a fairly low-level tool and should be kept that way, in my opinion.  Warnings are great... it'll get someone to the solution quickly.

Comment: I proposed an option, not mandatory blocking. The problem with a warning is that the file is destroyed if the other end doesn't accommodate same URL rewrites.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I know that at the same time read and write operation not working with the same file name, But the problem is not that. Actually, my problem is that it decreases the duration of the audio file.

Comment: @PinalPatel That clearly is your problem.... pretty hard to read from a file when a particular block has already been removed, and thus the truncation.